# Unable to display uploaded image file

Tags: django

I am currently using this structure to upload images on my site:

I am testing on my localhost:8000

In my setting.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my Photo model I defined the following:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='site_images')
```

The image uploads correctly but whenever I do the following:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
     <div class="col-md-3 photo-wrapper">
         <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}"/>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In the page source it is looking for the following URL where it is unable to retrieve the photo from:

```
http://media/profile_photos/photo_name.jpeg
```

How would one go about fixing this?

Comment: How does the main `urls.py` look like?

Comment: Does it open your photo on `http://localhost:8000/media/profile_photos/photo_name.jpeg` ?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I am having the same issue I am not able to open the file typing the link

Comment: @SachinDivakar Did you set up `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: @SachinDivakar I suggest creating separate question, because I think we will need more info

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev try changing the MEDIA_URL to 'media/' instead of '/media/', that was what solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` that should be `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'`, someone answered this but I see he removed his answer. This fixed my problem and images are now shown.